# Analytic Contiuation of $\int_0^\infty {t^{z-1}\sin t}\,dt $

Tags: integration

I do not have a deep understanding of analytic continuation, so I want to be sure.
Are the following assertions true?

I am asked to prove that $\int_0^\infty {t^{z-1}\sin t}\,dt = \sin(\frac{\pi z}{2})\Gamma(z)$ whenever $-1<\text{re}(z)<1$

My strategy is as following:

First step: $\Gamma(z) e^{i \pi z/2} = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{it}\, dt$ for $0<\text{re}(z)<1$.

Second Step: Since when $0<\text{re}(z)<1$ , $\int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{it}\, dt$ is converging, take imaginary part of it;

Then what we have reached so far is $\int_0^\infty t^{z-1} \sin t\, dt = \Gamma(z) \sin(\frac{\pi z}{2})$ for $0<\text{re}(z)<1$.

Third Step: Define $f(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1} \sin t\, dt $ and $g(z) =\Gamma(z) \sin(\frac{\pi z}{2})$

Fourth Step: Show that $f$ is analytic in $-1<\text{re}(z)<1$ and $g$ is analytic in $0<\text{re}(z)<1$.

Fifth Step: Since $f=g$ on $0<\text{re}(z)<1$, by using analytic continuation, $f=g$ on $-1<\text{re}(z)<1$.